# Nonparametric Regression with Convolution Responses

Tags: nonlinear-regression

Here's the problem I have. I have a set of measurements $f_i \pm \sigma_i$ as a result of some measurement process. In reality, there is a continuous signal $g(x)$ for $x \in D \subset \mathbb{R}$ that is incident on my detector, and the detector digitizes $g$ into the measured $f_i$ using some function $H_i$, so that $f_i = \int_D H_i(x) g(x) dx $.

My question is, how do I infer $g(x)$ for all $x \in D$, with uncertainty? You can assume that $H_i$ are known exactly. There is no reason to assume any form for $g$, other than that it should be relatively smooth. One way would be to assume some form for $g$, e.g. a cubic spline with $k$ control points, and find the spline coefficients that minimize $\chi^2$, but I was wondering if there was a method where I could enforce some level of smoothness to it. If $H_i$ was a delta function, I would use a Gaussian Process, but I'm not sure how I would do that here.

Bonus points if uncertainty in $H_i$ can somehow be accomodated.